# gyp errors when trying to install Parcel with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, parcel, gyp

I'm trying to install Parcel, I used both NPM and Yarn, and tried several Node.js versions (14, 16, 10...) but nothing worked for me, I always get the same error. I'm using Windows 10 32bit and Python

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | ia32
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.0 found at \"C:\\Users\\ALI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311-32\\python.exe\" 
gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.28307.1831) found at:
gyp info find VS \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\\Users\\ALI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311-32\\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\gyp\\\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\ALI\\\\Desktop\\\\osamasoliman\\\\node_modules\\\\msgpackr-extract\\\\build\\\\config.gypi',       
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\ALI\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.13.0\\\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\ALI\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.13.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\ALI\\\\\\\\AppData\\\\\\\\Local\\\\\\\\node-gyp\\\\\\\\Cache\\\\\\\\16.13.0\\\\\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\ALI\\\\Desktop\\\\osamasoliman\\\\node_modules\\\\msgpackr-extract',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\ALI\\\\Desktop\\\\osamasoliman\\\\node_modules\\\\msgpackr-extract\\\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp: C:\\Users\\ALI\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.13.0\\common.gypi not found (cwd: C:\\Users\\ALI\\Desktop\\osamasoliman\\node_modules\\msgpackr-extract) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\lib\\configure.js:353:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
gyp ERR! command \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node.exe\" \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\bin\\\\node-gyp.js\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\\Users\\ALI\\Desktop\\osamasoliman\\node_modules\\msgpackr-extract
gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
gyp ERR! not ok"
info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
PS C:\Users\ALI\Desktop\osamasoliman>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that is installed all correctly?

Here it says that he did not found this:

**C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\16.13.0\common.gypi not found**

See if you can install another packages. If not, try to re-install